# iOS 5 check for internet connection

Tags: ios5, networking

I'm developing an iOS 5.1 app and I need to check for internet connection and which type of connection it is.

What is the most efficient way to go about this simple check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apples' reachability might help, it worked nicely for me:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. I personally just disabled ARC for that file. In case you're unaware, this may be done as shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project